# PrimeNg TabView with ConfirmDialog not working

Tags: angular8, primeng

I'm trying to use PrimeNg TabView component along with confirmDialog unsuccessfully
I am able to show this confirm dialog but it appears after user switch to target tab panel which is wrong.

```
<p-tabView (onChange)="handleChange($event)" [(activeIndex)]="index">...</p-tabView> 


handleChange(e) {
  this.confirmationService.confirm({
      message: 'There are unsaved changes, do you want to proceed?',
      accept:  () => {
      this.index = e.index;
      },
      reject:() =>{        }
      });
}
```

Do you have an idea on how to prevent or allow tab change using confirm dialog ?

Thanks

Comment: Add more details and running sample code.

Comment: @aviboy2006 I am able to show this confirm dialog but it appears after user switch to target tab panel which is wrong.

Comment: @PrakashAbhay have you check my answer is it work for you 

Answer (score 4, accepted):

there is no official way to prevent change to another tab by press on that tab , but  there is a work around it first we need to prevent the tab change by tab click,

1️⃣ we need to set the header by ng-template or it called a custom header

*template*

```html
    <p-tabPanel >
        <ng-template pTemplate="header">
            <div (click)="handleChange($event,0)">
                Godfather I
            </div>
        </ng-template>

         .....

    </p-tabPanel>
```

2️⃣ we bind a click event to the new header text and by using mouse event `stopPropagation` method we can prevent the change ,now we can control the change by confirm result but you need to pass the current tab `index`, that why I add another parameter to `handleChange`

*component*

```js
 handleChange(e:MouseEvent,tabIndex:number) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    if (this.index == tabIndex){
      return;
    }
    // console.log(tabIndex)
    this.confirmationService.confirm({
      message: "There are unsaved changes, do you want to proceed?",
      accept: () => {
        this.index = tabIndex;
      },
      reject: () => {}
    });
  }
```

> the if block `if (this.index == tabIndex){return;}` use to prevent showing the confirm dialog if we click on the same active tab again

[**demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-tabview-change-by-confirm?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Comment: Thanks @malbarmavi.